# problem with multline

Tags: multline

I have a problem with multline command when I would like to handle long equation 
here is the code:

```
\begin{multline}
 \gamma(w_{i-1}, ..., w_{i-n+1}) = \frac{D_{1} N_{1}(w_{i-1}^{w_{i-n+1}} w') +   D_{2} N_{2}(w_{i-1}, ..., w_{i-n+1} w')    
\\ +  D_{3_{+}} N_{3_{+}}(w_{i-1}, ..., w_{i-n+1} w')                 }{\sum_{w_{i}}N(w_{i} ...w_{i-n+1}^{i})}
\end{multline}
```

the error is: extra "}"

But I dont find the mistake

Can you help me please?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As far as I can see, you have fraction over two line. This is not allowed. And please, instead of code fragment provide complete, minimal (non)working example (MWE) which start with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`. With this you will help to people who like to help you ...

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/error-with-multline-but-not-equation?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on egreg's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/error-with-multline-but-not-equation?rq=1), the issue seems to be that you can't split lines in the middle of the numerator. (Though I'm making some assumptions on `documentclass` here...) Here's one possible fix, since the denominator is relatively short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  \gamma(w_{i-1}, ..., w_{i-n+1}) =
  \frac{1}{{\sum_{w_{i}}N(w_{i} ...w_{i-n+1}^{i})}} \Bigl(
  D_{1} N_{1}(w_{i-1}^{w_{i-n+1}} w') + \\ 
  D_{2} N_{2}(w_{i-1}, ..., w_{i-n+1} w') +
  D_{3_{+}} N_{3_{+}}(w_{i-1}, ..., w_{i-n+1} w')\Bigr)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

For this is used macro `\splitfrac{...}{...}` from package `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\gamma(w_{i-1},\dots,w_{i-n+1})
    = \dfrac{\splitfrac{D_{1} N_{1}(w_{i-1}^{w_{i-n+1}} w') 
                        + D_{2} N_{2}(w_{i-1},\dots,w_{i-n+1} w')}   
                      { + D_{3_{+}} N_{3_{+}}(w_{i-1},\dots,w_{i-n+1} w')}
           }{\sum_{w_{i}}N(w_{i},\dots,w_{i-n+1}^{i})}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```